# How to get the atoms in the residue using Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I am working with Biopython. I want to find out the atoms in a residue.

```
from Bio import PDB

pdb = "1dly.pdb"
name = pdb[:3]

p = PDB.PDBParser()
s = p.get_structure(name, pdb)

y = s.get_residues()
for x in y:
    print x, x.resname
```

I got the residue name but I need to get the atoms inside the residue. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Iterating over a [Residue object](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.Residue.Residue-class.html) will yield the atoms within:

```
for res in s.get_residues():
    for atom in res:
        print atom
```

---

If you're looking to obtain the atoms from some arbitrary [`Entity`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.Entity-module.html) or list of `Entity` objects, you might want to try [`unfold_entities`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.Selection-module.html#unfold_entities):

```
for atom in PDB.Selection.unfold_entities([res_1, res_2], target_level='A'):
    print atom
```

Additionally, [`Structure`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.PDB.Structure.Structure-class.html) objects have a method `get_atoms()` that will yield all atoms within the structure.